# Getting a blank page when running PHP file (Maybe MySQL's Fault?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've not edited my PHP file in over 3 weeks, and up until 2 weeks ago everything was working fine, now when I go to use the form to send the e-mail, I just get taken to a white page. Even the HTML doesn't display, I'm thinking this is because the PHP Exits early and so never sends the code. After this I looked at why it was exiting, the only way the file could exit early was on the or die(mysql_error()) function and so it leads me to believe that the SQL is not working properly, sure enough the problem is not reported into the database, but the e-mail is able to be sent when I remove the or die part of the statement.

Is there something wrong with this SQL? it seems to me that it's right. But I would appreciate someone pointing out any obvious errors, I would also like to note that for a week this Statement worked, so would it have to be something to do with the MySQL database itself?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reported_problems (`time_of_report`, `Full Name`, `E-mail`, `Phone Number`, `House Number`, `First Line`, `City`, `Postcode`, `Problem Type`, `Description`, `Urgency`) VALUES(now(),'$fullname','$tenantemail','$phonenumber','$housenumber','$streetname','$city','$postcode','$typeofproblem','$probdesc','$severity_desc')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also just want to note that I don't actually recieve any mysql_error at all... which is weird because I normally would.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT - this is the db_conx.php file I use to make the initial connection

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("mysql.pipeten.co.uk", "********", "********", "MouseAc_mouseaccount");
// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();}

?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting. You shouldn't have to be guessing what error you are getting.

Comment: Also, you're not using mysql but mysql `i`. So there is no error recorded.

Comment: adding to what @JohnConde said, if you can't (for whatever reason) turn on error reporting in php.ini, (you're not an admin, etc.) google where to find your php error log, and `tail` that file to get the last errors. In there you should be able to see the error(s). Just from looking at the query, it could be a few things, maybe some of the input variables you're injecting are NULL and the db is refusing to insert that data because of it. Can you verify that the data is still added even with the script dying?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) instead:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /hsphere/local/home/mouseaccount/mouseaccount.com/php_includes/problem_form_email.php on line 137  Is the error that I get? Any idea what this means?

Comment: It means that you're not passing in the required parameter, which should be your mysqli connection. You might be having problems with that initial connection. Can you verify that it's connecting to the database properly? Add more of your code to your initial post.

Comment: surely DB_conx would throw up an error if it couldn't make the connection?

Comment: It should. Check the output of var_dump($db_conx) before you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the error, after turning on Errors, it appears that the error was caused by it trying to insert an ID into a field that hadn't been checked to Auto Increment, Thanks for telling me how to get the errors to show up properly :)